# How fix the flickering issue while scrolling using javascript observer and css sticky

Tags: javascript, css, sass, observers, intersection-observer

When my specific element got sticky one of its element font size should decrease and get smaller. In this situation I can't use only CSS sticky and I needed to use javascript observer and CSS sticky together.

When scroll achieve my target element it is flickering and it frequently gives and takes the class `is-pinned`.

I searched a lot but can't find my solution so what can I do to fix the flickering issue in scrolling?

```js
const stickyElement = document.querySelector('.sticky-section');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle('is-pinned', e.intersectionRatio < 1), {
  threshold: [1],
  root: sidebar,
});

observer.observe(stickyElement);
```

```css
.sidebar {
  padding-left: var(--navigation-size-min);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-section {
  background-color: var(--white);
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  overflow-anchor: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  h1 {
    font-size: var(--font-size-headline-primary);
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
    color: var(--ui-accent-1);
    margin: calc(6 * var(--base-size)) 0;
  }
  &.is-pinned {
    h1 {
      font-size: var(--font-size-headline-quaternary);
      margin-bottom: var(--base-size);
    }
    &+.sidebar-content {
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sticky-section">
    <h1>My title which its font-size should decrease </h1>
    <div class="search-box">
      <button>
        <img src="./images/icons/search-alternate.svg" alt="search icon" />
      </button>
      <input type="search" placeholder="search ..." />
    </div>
    <div class="report-grid-header">
      <div>Teilenummer</div>
      <div>Typ</div>
      <div>Benotigt</div>
      <div>Verspatung</div>
      <div>Status</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-content"></div>
</div>
```